# What does Win+Shift+F4 do?

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-gnome, shortcut-keys

I am trying to assign keys to commands in **Settings** > **Keyboard**, but I am not able to assign
<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, although I was able to assign <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd> with the same combination.

***Edit***: I first tried searching for that in Keyboard Settings GUI, but that didn't appear, hence I tried checking with the following command in terminal

```
gsettings list-recursively  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | sort | more
```

for <kbd>F4</kbd>, but found only `Alt + F4`.

- How do I assign <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> to something? (Or remove the existing keybinding)
- How do I see globally what command a key combination is assigned to?

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome

Comment: If that key combo is assigned, you could just try it and see what happens.

Comment: whats your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 0):

To see what key combo's are assigned:
`System Settings` > `Shortcuts` > `Global Shortcuts`
You can also check/edit standard or custom Shortcuts.

"win" key will be listed as `meta` or `super`.

[image: shortcuts preferences]

---

I'm running Kubuntu, so your system settings may look different.

Answer (score 0):

as a Workaround you may follow this..

when you try to assign <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
the actual sequence it is assigning is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>

in the same way you can assign <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> key combo.. it does not have any pre-assigned short cut as i did not get any warning..

[image]